# Presidential Approval Ratings

Tags: central-limit-theorem

> Assume that 47% of Americans support Obama. We pick a random sample of
>   size 100 from the population of all Americans. What is the
>   probability, that the relative share of those who support Obama in the
>   sample is less than 40 %?

**Solution attempt:**

Let $\widehat p$ denote the sample proportion of Americans that support Obama. The CLT tells us $${\widehat p_n} = {\widehat p_{100}}{ \approx _D}N\left( {0.47,\,\frac{{(0.47)(1 - 0.47)}}{{100}}} \right)$$

From the description of the problem we need to find: $$P({\widehat p_{100}} < 0.4) = P\left( {\frac{{{{\widehat p}_{100}} - 0.47}}{{\sqrt {\frac{{(0.47)(1 - 0.47)}}{{100}}} }} < \frac{{0.4 - 0.47}}{{\sqrt {\frac{{(0.47)(1 - 0.47)}}{{100}}} }}} \right) \approx P\left( {Z <  - 1.40} \right)$$ $$P\left( {Z <  - 1.40} \right) = 0.0808$$

Not sure if i have a right answer...